# Add new endpoint to existing App Engine backend server in Android Studio

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have an App Engine backend with Google Cloud Messaging setup in my local Android Studio.

It has the original endpoints as follows:

- Messaging Endpoint
- Registration Endpoint

I have created a new Java file and added a new class called `UserRegistration` as follows:

```
package com.xxxxx.gcmbackend;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.inject.Named;

import static com.xxxxxx.gcmbackend.OfyService.ofy;

@Api(
        name = "register",
        version = "v1",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "gcmbackend.xxxxx.com",
                ownerName = "gcmbackend.xxxxx.com",
                packagePath=""
        )
)


public class UserRegistrationEndpoint {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationEndpoint.class.getName());
    @ApiMethod(name = "register")
    public void registerDevice(@Named("regId") String regId, @Named("username") String username, @Named("phone") String phone) {
        if(findRecord(regId) != null) {
            log.info("Device " + regId + " already registered, skipping register");
            return;
        }
        RegistrationRecord record = new RegistrationRecord();
        record.setRegId(regId);
        record.setUsername(username);
        record.setPhone(phone);
        ofy().save().entity(record).now();
    }
    private RegistrationRecord findRecord(String regId) {
        return ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).filter("regId", regId).first().now();
    }
}
```

However, when deployed, I don't see this endpoint in the API explorer. How do I add a new working endpoint to an App Engine backend with Google Cloud Messaging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through existing code structure, I found out that every new API must be added to the `web.xml` file. I added my new endpoint as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
  <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.xxxxx.gcmbackend.RegistrationEndpoint, com.xxxxx.gcmbackend.MessagingEndpoint, com.xxxxx.gcmbackend.UserRegistrationEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```